# Regular expression for 2 or 5 digits

Tags: regex

How do I write a regular expression that can match only numbers with 2 or 5 digits?

I have this so far but it matches any number with 2 to 5 digits.

```
           ^\d{2,5}$
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use 3 optional digits:

```
^\d{2}\d{3}?$
```

Note that some regex engines will interpret the `?` after any repetition modifier (even a fixed one) as an ungreedy modifier, which seems to cause problems for the case of two digits. If you experience this, use:

```
^\d{2}(?:\d{3})?$
```

You can read up on some regex basics in [this great tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

By the way, the above is effectively equivalent (but marginally more efficient) to this one using alternation:

```
^(?:\d{2}|\d{5})$
```

(Just for the sake of showing you another regex concept.)

Comment: -1. The first one is wrong in Java. The `?` will indicate lazy matching.

Comment: @nhahtdh, only if the `{..}` was a range, or not?

Comment: @m.buettner: I don't think differ from normal when the number of repetition is fixed, but the `?` will be interpreted as laziness.

Comment: @m.buettner: This case is quite intriguing, since Java takes the `?` as laziness, but ruby takes it as greedy zero or one. I think you should edit your answer to use the 2nd case only, since it will maximize the compatibility.

Comment: @nhahtdh, I added a fix to the first variant

Comment: @m.buettner: How can you say about the efficiency of one regex over the other?

Comment: @nhahtdh think about what the engine does. in the first case it will try 5, if that doesn't work it will throw away 3 and check whether it's only 2. in the latter case, it tries 2. if that doesn't work it throws away the 2 and starts over to match 5. so in the case of 2 digits the latter is one step faster (but if wouldn't be if we made the `?` in the first version ungreedy). whereas in all other case, the first one will be slightly faster, since it will never throw away the first two matched digits. in any case that does not start with two digits, the first version will also abort earlier.

Comment: @m.buettner: I don't have concrete evidence to say that you are wrong, but I am not convinced with argument based on just how the regex is written. The regex may look different, but after transformation into a DFA, it is possible that they become the same and there will be no performance different.

Comment: @nhahtdh well surely a regex engine might apply optimizations, which might make these the same. however, as far as I know my description is widely how regex engines work (check out the www.regular-expressions.info, it contains a lot of how engines work internally). but if you want, I'll gladly remove that claim from my answer

Comment: @m.buettner: I think you can leave it there, until someone can totally deny your point.

Comment: `new RegExp('^(?:\\d{1,3})$', 'gi').test(value) ? '' : 'Use valid dial code'` this will give me num between 1-3

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\A\d{2}\z$|^\A\d{5}\z$/
```

`A` meaning start of input and `z` meaning end of input.

This works for PHP and JAVA; not sure about js or perl.